# How to run electron app in linux after it is packaged using electron packager

Tags: node.js, linux, electron, electron-packager

Electron is known to run application in different platforms ( windows and linux ). I am running simple hello world program.
**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello World!</title>
        <!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
        Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
        and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
      </body>
    </html>
```

**main.js**

```
    const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
    function createWindow () {
        // Create the browser window.
        let win = new BrowserWindow({
          width: 800,
          height: 600,
          webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
         }
        })

        // and load the index.html of the app.
        win.loadFile('index.html')
      }

      app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

This is my app structure
app
|-package.json
|-node_modules
|-main.js (entry point)
|-index.html

I am trying to run the application in linux CentOS.

I built the app using electron-packagerfor windows and linux .For linux I used following command

```
 "builderlinux":"electron-packager ./ --out Linux64 --overwrite --platform linux --arch x64"
```

This is linux os

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
```

I expected the packaged app to work in linux but it doesn't

This is the error I see

./LICENSE
./LICENSE: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `c'
./LICENSE: line 1:`Copyright (c) 2013-2019 GitHub Inc.'

But in windows , I see app working correctly

[image]
Can someone try to package this simple electron app using electron builder and try to run in linux and tell me procedure

Any suggestions on running electron after it is packaged using electron packager will be of great help

Comment: Did you get it working then?